# How shall I crop images with 2 colour borders in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, rotation, crop

My original image was this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzkQX.png)

After I rotate them, I got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7SBm.png)

Therefore, I am currently having both black and white borders. I only want the middle part of the image, how can I crop them with Python?

I am new here, appreciate if anyone can help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should post your code... this is about coding problems after all -- I'll recommend OpenCV APIs but the equivalent can be had in most libraries that deal with image processing -- consider first image. calculate mask for contents vs background (inRange on white, then invert). if it's noisy, clean that up somehow. then calculate the minAreaRect. that'll give you a center and rotation and size, and also the four corner points. you can then plug that into whatever rotation or affine transform you need.

Comment: Thanks! I will post my code later, I somehow managed to do it, but I would like to try for other methods